# How long can stock exchanges stay closed and with what consequences?

Tags: stock-market

Sometimes, states deliberately close their stock exchanges and keep them closed for a long time (longer than the usual nights/weekends). As far as I understand, this a drastic measure, something done only in dire need of stabilising the exchange against an emergency.

But just how big are the downsides of prolonging the closed status - how long can it feasibly be maintained closed, and what would be the fallout resulting from such multi-day closures? Can the closure be indefinite, and what are the consequences if *that* happens?

Comment: There was human civilization before stock exchanges, so the apparent answer is "forever". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_without_a_stock_exchange - the real question here is about consequences

Comment: @user253751 Do you really "close" a stock exchange that has never existed? If yes, then the brothel in your appartment has been closed for years! (I assume.)

Comment: The Soviet Union closed the (imperial) Russian stock exchange for more than 70 years.

Comment: "*What are the consequences*"? It is unclear to me whose consequences you mean, but I am pretty sure the answer will be "it depends on the circumstances and details."